# How can I create an alias within a collection dynamically in XStream

Tags: xstream

I have a pretty complex object tree (basically trying to serialize objects into XML). The objects can contain other objects of the same type or another etc.

Anyway, I annotated the alias on each class, and it works well up to a certain extent. When the nesting level is beyond 3, the aliases stop working.

For instance, I have

```
  private List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

This contains objects with an annotated alias. But they don't work here anymore, I get the generic Class name.

If I annotate something like this

```
  @XStreamAlias(value = "value-date", impl = ValueDate.class)
  private List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

it works, but I can't use the annotation several times. Ideally, I would do the following:

```
  @XStreamAlias(value = "value-text", impl = ValueText.class)
  @XStreamAlias(value = "value-boolean", impl = ValueBoolean.class)
  @XStreamAlias(value = "value-date", impl = ValueDate.class)
  private List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would expect something like

```
  <values>
    <value-date>1999-08-31</value-date>
  </values>
```

But I get

```
  <values>
    <sql-date>1999-08-31</sql-date>
  </values>
```

My class looks like this

```
@XStreamAlias("value-date")
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = { "date" })
public class ValueDate {

  private Date date;
```

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to say  :-)

I just started with XStream, because JAXB was driving me crazy  ;-)

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the error: I was trying to put a java.sql.Date directly into my List instead of wrapping it into a ValueDate.

Now everything works as expected.